CSS Watermark & Page Numbers for ColdFusion cfcontent='application/msword'
I'm outputting a query into a cfcontent type='application/msword'. I'd like to add page numbers and a watermark of "Confidential" on the background of each page generated in the word doc.
This is the page where I call the object
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='inline; filename="#prc.filename#"' charset="utf-8">
    <cfcontent type="application/msword; charset=utf-8" reset="yes">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>

    <cfoutput>#prc.objAgenda.getAgendaText()#</cfoutput>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").attr("xmlns:o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
    $("html").attr("xmlns:w", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
   // $("html").attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");
    });
    </script>

My function calls this page as the body and the div - agendaBody is where I'd like the watermark and page numbers to be applied
<div class="agendaBody">
    <div class="border border-dark text-center bg-light">
        AGENDA<br>
        <cfoutput>#prc.SchoolName#</cfoutput> Conflict of Interest Committee<br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <ol style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:15px;">
        <li>Review and Approval of Interim COI Actions</li>
        <li>COI Case Reviews</li>
        <li>Updates</li>
        <li>Next Meeting:</li>
    </ol>
    <hr style="color:black;"></hr>
    <p style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>Actions since last meeting:</strong><br><br></p>
    <p style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>EXPEDITED REVIEWS</strong></p>
    <p style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>New Relationships</strong></p>
    <cfoutput>#listDisclosures(prc.new_fcoi,'FCOI Management')#</cfoutput>
    
    </div>

I have tried various css and bootstrap scripts and can't seem to get the styling to carry into the word doc - and I can't remotely figure out page numbering. It may not be possible?
.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
*/

<div class="watermark">
           CONFIDENTIAL
</div> 


Does it have to be word document? Those tasks are easily done with PDFs in ACF.

Also, maybe this is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456413/creating-a-word-document-in-coldfusion-how-to-have-pagenumbering
